# Closed set of states for Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Here is the definition of closed set of states in Durrett.  Let $X_n$ be a markov chain.

> $C$ is closed if $x\in C$ and $\rho_{xy}>0$ implies $y\in C$ where $\rho_{xy}$ is the probability of transfer from $x$ to $y$. i.e. $T_y=\inf\{n\geq 1, X_n=y\}$, $\rho_{xy}=P_x(T_y<\infty)$

Then there is a remark on the book.

> $P_x(X_n\in C)=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I can see that this is true if the state space $S$ is countable. However, when the state space $S$ is uncountable, I am not quite sure this is true.

If the state space is $[0,1]$ and the transition probability $p(x,\cdot)$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ for all $x$. It seems like $\rho_{xy}=0$ for all $x,y\in [0,1]$. But in this case, what are the closed set of states? Is it all singletons or $[0,1]$. I feel like the closed set of states is undefined in this case. Currently, I am using the 5th edition of Durrett's Probability Theory and Example. In the context,  there is no restriction on the state space. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My reading is that any subset of $[0,1]$ would be a closed set of states, since the implication would be vacuously true.

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused That's a bit tricky... The def seems to be equivalent to " $C$ is closed if for $x\in C$ and $y\in C^c$ implies $\rho_{xy}=0$. It looks like in this case $C$ can be any subset of $[0,1]$?